# Smoother transition moving cursor with a coordinates given

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

In a .NET C# program, I have to simulate the "mouse" cursor movement with coordinates received in the events of a external controller.

I did get to move the cursor depending on these coordinates.

Is there any possibility to move the cursor of a smoother way between two points?, because when I have 2 away points there is like a "jump" with the cursor.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added code, this function is launched each time new coordinates are received (aprox. each 20-30 ms)

```
//...
private void MoveCursor (int x, int y){
    //Added checkup for avoiding noise between closer points 
    if (Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.X - x)>10 || Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.Y - y)>10){
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x,y)
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that you're using right now?

Comment: If you receive a coordinate every 20-30 ms, you are already close to the likely refresh rate of the screen. In that case there is nothing much to do without sacrificing the precision.

Comment: @Ndech As you can see above, I am trying avoiding noise, so I am putting a distance, for example, of 30px, there is less noise, but "jumps" are produced. I would like create transition between 2 points, doesn't matter if delay is produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally inspired by @Ndech solution I could solve my problem.
I've divided the solution into 2 parts:

1. This is the event which is raised by my gaze controller (each 20ms aprox). I discard closer points to avoid "jumps" due to the way as gaze controller works.

   ```
   private void MoveCursorEvent (object sender, GazePointEventArgs e){
      if (Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.X - e.X) > 40 || Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.Y - e.Y) > 40){
          MoveCursor((int)e.X, (int)e.Y);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Copying current values of X,Y point of the cursor in a primitive variable since Cursor.Position could change during the process (Check if the first time…) Adding to previous point, average distance between previous point and current point with a weight of 15%. And Updating Cursor.Position with the new position calculated.

   ```
   //Declare position variables
   int previousX = 0;
   int previousY = 0;


   private void MoveCursor (int newX, int newY){

      //If first time, set.
      if (previousX == 0)
          previousX = newX;

      if (previousY == 0)
          previousY = newY;


      //Calculate new position
      previousX = (int)(((newX - previousX) /2) * 0.15f);
      previousY = (int)(((newY - previousY) /2) * 0.15f);

      //Update position
      Cursor.Position = new Point (previousX, previousY);

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, here is a simple solution (syntax untested) that I use in one of my software and that I suggest you to test to see if it fits your needs :

```
Point _targetPosition;
Point _currentPosition;

private void MoveCursor (int x, int y){
    _targetPosition = new Point(x,y);
    _currentPosition += (_targetPosition - _currentPosition)*0.08f;
    Cursor.Position = _currentPosition;
}
```

Basically, I maintain a target position which is the last coordinate received. I move the cursor only by a fraction (here 8% of the distance between the current position and the target).

It very efficiently smooths the movement of the mouse but lead to imprecision and a delay that may not be acceptable for brutal movement or changes of direction.

A factor of 8% give good results in my case considering 60 updates/seconds but that factor need to be adapted to your data.

Comment: I am working over your idea but the cursor tends to go to the 4 screen corners...

Comment: Normally the pointer should only move in the direction of the latest received coordinates. I just roughly translated a code sample I had in DirectX to your case, I'm not sure that the Point structure defines the proper overloads for the line `_currentPosition += (_targetPosition - _currentPosition)*0.08f;` to work.